# Enterasys - Ports not working after power surge, but then work later on

Tags: switch

We run all Enterasys switches (C and B) stacks. All my switches are behind some pretty good surge and battery backups (APC and Tripplite).

3 Days ago we had a power surge at our company. Nothing shut down, but I had ports on some of my switches that stopped working. Even though lights were blinking like data was going through and [Netsight](http://www.extremenetworks.com/product/netsight/) was not reporting anything wrong. I was getting timeouts like crazy. It took me a while to finally figure out that all I had too do was unplug the cable from the port and plug it back in and everything return back to normal.

One of the ports that had an issue was the fiber connection which I use a [Proline AGM731F](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Proline-AGM731F-Compatible-1000Base-SX-MMF-SFP-mini-GBIC-module/2261646.aspx) connector for that. I had to unplug it and replug it and everything works fine. This is the second time I have had this issue where ports stop working for no reason.

What makes it difficlut to deal with is that no errors, collisions, packet loss are being reported even though I can simply ping and get timeouts.

Any idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered your "pretty good surge protection" may be utter crap? The symptoms you describe point to that. Note that power issues can stem from a bad electrical switch WITHIN the protected area - I know a server room where servers did reboot when someone turned on the lights. Granted, this is rare, but something points to  either the power quality being bad / surge protection being crap and / or a source within the protected network. Btw., you do have separate grounding for that surge protection? I kindly remember the day they put that loooong metal pole down in the earth at the back of our office - 3 meters deep - for the surge protection.

Comment: I have to admit that I cannot guarantee that the grounding is properly routed with this equipment. I also am questioning the right amount of voltage coming out of the outlets as well. I am going to request some testing done on the outlets and confirm that the ground is actually working. Thanks for the input